# Cut 4 digits from AD DisplayName

Tags: string

I have googled and used the PS help as much as possible but can't find a definitive resolution to the seemingly small issues that I have.

My users have [ZZ] at the end of their displayName of their AD accounts and as part of a migration project we are required to lose those 4 characters.  I've tried:
    Trim
    TrimEnd
    Rename-Item $*($*.DisplayName -replace "[ZZ]", "")

..and other suggestions to no avail.

any help will be greatly appreciated.

(I can't add the code as I should due to browser restrictions.  sorry.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to set the new AD User DisplayName directly, the below will search the whole of AD for users with "[ZZ]" in their DisplayName and remove the characters and set the new DisplayName.

```
$UsersWithZZ = get-aduser -Filter 'DisplayName -like "*[ZZ]"' -Properties *
foreach ($User in $UsersWithZZ){
    $NewDN = ($User.DisplayName).TrimEnd("[ZZ]")
    Set-ADUser -Identity $User.SamAccountName -DisplayName $NewDN
}
```

Hopefully this helps.